# Linq, how to put a indexes on Linq Query

Tags: development

I want to render a dates from list to the ASP Calendar.

My list look like this:

```
Kontrakt | Pracownik | Dzien | ID | Procenty
--------------------------------------------
```

I made Linq Query, but it's doing quite long, about 3-4 secunds. How to put indexes on it?

```
     `   SPWeb witryna = SPContext.Current.Web;
        SPListItemCollection listaDniNaProjektDropDownList = witryna.Lists["Szczegoly"].Items;
        //Link technology
            QumakDataContext qumak = new QumakDataContext("http://gzawistowskilap");
            var szczegoly = from szczegolyQumak in qumak.Szczegoly
                            orderby szczegolyQumak.Dzien 

                            select new {szczegolyQumak.Dzien, szczegolyQumak.Kontrakt};

            foreach(var zmiennaSzczegoly in szczegoly ){

                Label1.Text +=zmiennaSzczegoly.Dzien + zmiennaSzczegoly.Kontrakt + "<br />";
            }`
```

Comment: Hi Grzegorz, have you tried to use a StrinBuilder class to make the string that you want and after put it in Label1.Text ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexes are not created in SPQuery, but you can create indexes on columns involved in joins, where clauses from Indexed Column option:

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can read about Indexing and Query Throttling [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798465.aspx)

Also, as Salvatore Di Fazio said... replace the above code as below:

```
SPWeb witryna = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPListItemCollection listaDniNaProjektDropDownList = witryna.Lists["Szczegoly"].Items;
//Link technology
QumakDataContext qumak = new QumakDataContext("http://gzawistowskilap");
var szczegoly = from szczegolyQumak in qumak.Szczegoly
                orderby szczegolyQumak.Dzien 

               select new {szczegolyQumak.Dzien, szczegolyQumak.Kontrakt};
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);

foreach(var zmiennaSzczegoly in szczegoly ){
    str.Append(zmiennaSzczegoly.Dzien + zmiennaSzczegoly.Kontrakt + "<br />");
}

Label1.Text = str.ToString();
```

You will need to add reference as `using System.Text;`